# Fet array operation

Tags: transistors, mosfet, embedded, transistor-array

Can anyone explain to me the operation of the following FET arrray .

http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/DMN2019UTS.pdf

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what properties you don't understand, the question is otherwise too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide too many clues as to what you are interested in... By the way, it's all written in the datasheet you linked. This device is just 2 N-channel FETs in one package, with their drains connected. Nothing fancy. For example you can use it for high-side switching, as its Rdson and voltage range makes it suitable for the task.

Also recommended reading: [EETimes: A primer on high-side FET load switches (Part 1 of 2)](http://www.eetimes.com/design/industrial-control/4009943/A-primer-on-high-side-FET-load-switches-Part-1-of-2-)

Comment: What do you mean that it can be used for high speed switching?

Comment: high side. I did not say high speed. High side switching means that given an "ordinary" single supply setup, so the device requiring GND and a positive voltage to operate, this switch can be used to switch the positive voltage to the device. Low side switching in the same setup would mean breaking and connecting the "ground" line to the device.

Comment: Sorry, but the image is absolutely unreadable, I can't even figure o ut what's what, I'm not even able to find the FETs... You should try and upload it in a higher resolution...

Comment: I see your hungary website. Is there any way in can send you via email. Please...

Comment: I guess I dont have any other choice to share the schematic with you..inorder to nail down the issue.